# Showing extreme difference in responsive-design

Tags: responsive-design

Why the extreme responsive in the pc and mobile web page is different?

I've used the following code to create responsive......

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

in chrome resized

[image]

in iphone 5

[image]

Comment: you don't make a responsive website with just a tag. is the content responsive?

Comment: yes i add responsive.css and it work on chrome and firefox resize to 480 pixel

Comment: What is the problem? You use Chrome to resize the website to ~480 pixels wide and yet the iPhone version is 320 pixels wide and then observe the look different. What happens when you use Chrome to resize the website to 320 pixels wide?

Comment: any pixel in mobile has not suitable view . i test 480 pixel mobile but yet not work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Double check you have indeed included a veiwport meta tag in the head of your document, I'm not seeing it on the link you posted

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

(2) I'm seeing a 404 for http://foadalijani.com/include/css/top_nav.css

(3) Use web inspector to look for elements which may be breaking your responsive layout. e.g. Looks to me that that .home_menu_top_bg has a hard coded width of 890px which will cause problems. Maybe change this to a percentage. I think there are other elements with similar issues.

Good luck!

Comment: tnx . this is tag in head <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
and this link of responsive theme [responsive](http://foadalijani.com/include/css/responsive.css) . why only in mobile has problem???

Comment: @user3243573 , I'm still seeing problems with (2) and (3)

Comment: responsive work in chrome or firefox resized in pc but not work in mobile !!! i dont think css or class arent releavent !

Comment: I'm still seeing a problem with (2) from line 20 in your HTML.

Comment: sorry . check again [portfolio](http://foadalijani.com/en.php?loc=main&act=portfolio)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67478/discussion-between-david-taiaroa-and-user3243573).